# signing.properties Error (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use this Text app on Android Studio - https://github.com/tranleduy2000/text_converter . However, gradle build is failing (error message below). Please let me know what needs to be fixed for this to work.

Error:C:\Users...\Desktop\text\signing.properties (The system cannot find the file specified). Let me know what exactly is this keystore.properties and is it possible to create this file as it's not available in the github repo files.

Answer (score 0):

Replace app level `build.gradle` by below, I removed signin config, signin configs is key to use for releasing on playstore.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C)  2017-2018 Tran Le Duy
 *
 *  This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *  along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 401
        versionName "4.0.1"
    }


    sourceSets {
        main.res.srcDirs += 'src/main/res-cipher'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation project(':lvl')
    implementation project(':common')

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$androidSupportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$androidSupportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$androidSupportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$androidSupportVersion"

    implementation group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.simplecityapps:recyclerview-fastscroll:1.0.16'
    implementation 'io.github.kobakei:ratethisapp:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```